# Angular Httpclient has CORS error vs but fetch not

Tags: angular, angular8

I have noticed a Cross domain issue in my angular application.

If I use `fetch` method for xml file request, it works.

```
@Component({
  selector:    'app-xml',
  templateUrl: './app-xml.component.html'
})
export class HeroListComponent implements OnInit {
     constructor( private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

     getXml(){
         fetch(url).then((response:any) => {
             return response.text();
         }).then((text:any) => { console.log(text)})
     }
}
```

But if I use angular HttpClient, it throws a cross domain Xmlhttprequest error.

```
@Component({
  selector:    'app-xml',
  templateUrl: './app-xml.component.html'
})
export class HeroListComponent implements OnInit {
     constructor( private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

     getXml(){
         httpClient.get<any>(url).subscribe((response:any) => {
             console.log(text)
         })
     }
}
```

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use HttpClient, angular will by default add a Content-Type header, with value `application/json`

By having this header, the request to get the XML file is not a 'simple request' anymore, and so CORS chekcs will be performed.

More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Try specifying `responseType` as follows, this should set `Content-type` header to `text/plain` and prevent CORS checks. And that's probably what you want anyway since you are trying to retrieve an xml file, not json data.

```
httpClient.get<any>(url, {responseType : 'text'})
```

Comment: But `httpClient.get<any>(url, {responseType : 'text'})` has red line under `responseType `.

Comment: Your IDE should tell you what the problem is, but it's definitely part of the API

Answer (score 6):

Because Fetch API and XMLHttpRequest API have different capabilities. In this case [Angular uses XMLHttpRequest](https://angular.io/api/common/http#angularcommonhttp). While Fetch can perform no-cors requests XMLHttpRequest API can't. That's why.